# How to Retrieve value of xml node?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a xml file like this:

```
<Contacts>
   <CommandID>
       ShowInstalledProducts
   </CommandID>
</Contacts>
```

I need to iterate through a list of xml files and retrieve the value of `CommandId` ( in this case `ShowInstalledProducts`), for each ...

I am very new to xml. can someone please help me with the same. I am trying to achieve this using Linq. (other solutions are also welcome though)

DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"T:\Commands");
                FileInfo[] fileInfo = directoryInfo.GetFiles();

```
            foreach (FileInfo loop in fileInfo)
            {

                string doc = File.ReadAllText(loop.FullName);
                XmlDocument XMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
                XMLDoc.Load(doc);
                XMLDoc= stripDocumentNamespace(XMLDoc);
                //id = XMLDoc.Descendants("CommandID").First().Value;



            }
```

This is what i have done till now , im reading the files , and trying to ger the descendants. however there are multiple  in each xml file , and i need to retrieve the value of each . stuck here :(

Comment: What problem are you having? Are you unable to find any information on LINQ to XML?

Comment: You need to show us that you have tried something or at least done some research into your problem.

Comment: In which way you want to read xml file means javascript.

Comment: i just edited my question , to show what i have done till now ...

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1:** Go to [linqpad.net](http://www.linqpad.net/) and download the Linqpad application. It is a simple editor allowing you to write, run, and play around with Linq expression. Also, it has a lot of built in examples to learn from. (You might have to `select Help --> Veiw samples` to open this): 
[image]

**Step 2:** Paste the following code into the editor, and press F5 to run it (make sure `C# Statement(s)` is selected for "Language" above it though!). Play around and tweak it as you like / need.

```
var bench = XElement.Parse(@"<Contacts>
                <Node>
                    Something
                </Node>
                <Node>
    Something else
                </Node>
                </Contacts>");

var listOfNodes = bench.Elements(); 
listOfNodes.Dump();

var content = listOfNodes.Select(x => x.Value); 
content.Dump();
```

This should be enough to get you started. Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
fileInfo.SelectMany(fi => XDocument
                           .Load(fi.FullName)
                              .Descendants("CommandID")
                                .Select(e=>e.Value))
```

This LINQ code should return the list of all CommandId values of all files.